# button temporarily unresponsive when not in focus

Tags: reactjs

This very simple example has been driving me crazy:

```
import { useState } from "react";

const App = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  const handleButtonClick = () => {
    setCount((c) => c + 1);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <input type="text" />
      <button onClick={handleButtonClick}>+</button> {count}
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

The example runs fine most of the time - Clicking the button increments the counter.

However, if you:

1. click into the text box
2. type something
3. then click back on the button

You will find that **the button will often be unresponsive** for the following click or even for multiple following clicks. (The textbox is not even hooked up to do anything, it's there just to take focus away from the button.)

Take a look for yourself:
https://codesandbox.io/s/stoic-bell-big2up

Why is this?

Comment: Can't reproduce it, it's working fine for me in that sandbox. Also nothing in that code that would cause such an issue that I can see

Comment: Wow. I have it easily repro'ing on multiple browsers and multiple machines. I think I'm going crazy.